# Go reset a timer.NewTimer within select loop

Tags: go, timer, reset

I have a scenario in which I'm processing events on a channel, and one of those events is a heartbeat which needs to occur within a certain timeframe. Events which are not heartbeats will continue consuming the timer, however whenever the heartbeat is received I want to reset the timer. The obvious way to do this would be by using a  `time.NewTimer`.

For example:

```golang
func main() {
    to := time.NewTimer(3200 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-c:
            if !ok {
                return
            } else if event.Msg == "heartbeat" {
                to.Reset(3200 * time.Millisecond)               
            }
        case remediate := <-to.C:
            fmt.Println("do some stuff ...")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a `time.Ticker` won't work here as the remediation should only be triggered if the heartbeat hasn't been received, not every time.

The above solution works in the handful of low volume tests I've tried it on, however I came across a Github issue indicating that [resetting a Timer which has not fired is a no-no](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14038). Additionally the documentation states:

> Reset should be invoked only on stopped or expired timers with drained channels. If a program has already received a value from t.C, the timer is known to have expired and the channel drained, so t.Reset can be used directly. If a program has not yet received a value from t.C, however, the timer must be stopped and—if Stop reports that the timer expired before being stopped—the channel explicitly drained:

```golang
if !t.Stop() {
    <-t.C
}
t.Reset(d)
```

This gives me pause, as it seems to describe exactly what I'm attempting to do. I'm resetting the `Timer` whenever the heartbeat is received, prior to it having fired. I'm not experienced enough with Go yet to digest the whole post, but it certainly seems like I may be headed down a dangerous path.

One other solution I thought of is to simply replace the `Timer` with a new one whenever the heartbeat occurs, e.g:

```golang
else if event.Msg == "heartbeat" {
                to = time.NewTimer(3200 * time.Millisecond)               
            }
```

At first I was worried that the rebinding `to = time.NewTimer(3200 * time.Millisecond)`  wouldn't be visible within the select:

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send.

But in this particular case since we are inside a loop, I would expect that upon each iteration we re-enter select and therefore the new binding should be visible.  Is that a fair assumption?

I realize there are similar questions out there, and I've tried to read the relevant posts/documentation, but I am new to Go just want to be sure I'm understanding things correctly here.

So my questions are:

- Is my use of `timer.Reset()` unsafe, or are the cases mentioned in the Github issue highlighting other problems which are not applicable here? Is the explanation in the docs cryptic or do I just need more experience with Go?
- If it is unsafe, is my second proposed solution acceptable (rebinding the timer on each iteration).

**ADDENDUM**

---

Upon further reading, most of the pitfalls outlined in the issues are describing scenarios in which the timer has already fired (placing a result on the channel), and subsequent to that firing some other process attempts to Reset it. For this narrow case, I understand the need to test with `!t.Stop()` since a false return of Stop would indicate the timer has already fired, and as such must be drained prior to calling Reset.

What I still do not understand, is why it is necessary to call `t.Stop()` prior to `t.Reset()`, when the `Timer` has yet to fire.  None of the examples go into that as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think the problem of the "resetting a Timer which has not fired is a no-no" is applied in the example when using multiple goroutines. In your case, it should not be a problem. I believe.

What I find strange the solution given by the documentation (which has the `Stop` call) giving you a pause. It shouldn't because `Stop` returns `false` only if the timer is expired. Otherwise, `Reset` is non-blocking.

About your second question, if you need to recreate the `Timer`, just use a `time.After` instead. I think it would be "better".

Comment: @JotaSantos thanks for the reply.  Yes I realize that `Stop` will always return `true` in my example as the Timer never fires. What gives me pause is the statement "If a program has not yet received a value from t.C, however, the timer must be stopped and—if Stop reports that the timer expired before being stopped—the channel explicitly drained".

I realize I'll never need to drain the channel here, but that quote indicates that I still potentially need the call to `Stop` prior to `Reset`, and I wonder why that is?  What's the point of even having the `Reset` method if that's the case?

Comment: @JotaSantos also, I'm not sure how `time.After` can replace the need to either reset the timer or create a new one in this example. It would itself need to then be reset if the heartbeat wasn't received in time, so you're back where you started.

Comment: that is strange. It shouldn't. Just tested here and it is happening the same thing here. Which leads me to think we are approaching this the wrong way. I think an easy fix would be not to use the Timer and just use the `time.After` (which is a NewTimer btw). Another thing that could be done is to add a `select` when draining `<-to.C` (on the Stop "if") with a `default` clause. That would prevent the pause.

Comment: Because you are in a for loop, it will always reset (because `time.After` it is a NewTimer).

Comment: Another thing that I was wondering now, the title of your question refers to "ticker", but you are using a `Timer`. We do have a `Ticker` (use NewTicker) implementation that does not need to be "reset". It triggers each "x milliseconds" no matter what happens.

Comment: @JotaSantos Oops, I had the wrong title - fixed it, thank you for pointing that out!  For your comment on the `time.After`, I think maybe you're misunderstanding what I'm trying to do (and why time.After won't help).  Let's say I receive one of 3 msgs (a,b,c).  Only when I receive `c` do I want to reset the timer. For msg `a` and `b`, I want the timer to continue counting down.  If I used time.After in a select loop, it would always be restarted even when msg a and b are received.  Similarly if I used a Ticker, it would always fire, even if I receive c and would otherwise have reset the timer.

Comment: Got it, try using "select and default" when reading from `to.C` after stopping. This way it won't cause the pause. If `to.C` is empty, the `select` will go to the `default` "case".

Comment: I think that you might be able to use ticker. Each time you receive heartbeat you reset the ticker using separate channel. Then, only if you don't receive heartbeat for some time-period the ticker ticks and triggers your logic, so it's not happening every time, it only happens when heartbeat was not received for some period.

Comment: @michal.materowski Interesting idea but that adds some complexity versus the current solution of just resetting the timer.  Looking at this now, months later, I think I could have accomplished the same thing with a ticker vs timer at the top of main, since tickers also have a reset method.  I think the reason I didn't do that is because I don't need the ticker to keep ticking after entering the remediate section, since I just return there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I still do not understand, is why it is necessary to call t.Stop() prior to t.Reset(), when the Timer has yet to fire.

The "when the Timer has yet to fire" bit is critical here. The timer fires within a separate go routine (part of the [runtime](https://golang.org/src/runtime/time.go)) and this can happen at any time. You have no way of knowing whether the timer has fired at the time you call `to.Reset(3200 * time.Millisecond)` (it may even fire while that function is running!).

Here is an example that demonstrates this and is somewhat similar to what you are attempting (based on [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14383#issuecomment-276362874)):

```golang
func main() {
    eventC := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go keepaliveLoop(eventC )

    // Reset the timer 1000 (approx) times; once every millisecond (approx)
    // This should prevent the timer from firing (because that only happens after 2 ms)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        // Don't block if there is already a reset request
        select {
        case eventC <- struct{}{}:
        default:
        }
    }
}

func keepaliveLoop(eventC chan struct{}) {
    to := time.NewTimer(2 * time.Millisecond)

    for {
        select {
        case <-eventC: 
            //if event.Msg == "heartbeat"...
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond) // Simulate reset work (delay could be partly dur to whatever is triggering the
            to.Reset(2 * time.Millisecond)
        case <-to.C:
            panic("this should never happen")
        }
    }
}
```

Try it in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wKhyqN0Z41v).

This may appear contrived due to the `time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)` but that is just included to consistently demonstrate the issue. Your code may work 99.9% of the time but there is always the possibility that both the event and timer channels will fire before the `select` is run (in which a [random case](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) will run) or while the code in the `case event, ok := <-c:` block is running (including while `Reset()` is in progress). The result of this happening would be unexpected calls of the `remediate` code (which may not be a big issue).

Fortunately solving the issue is relatively easy (following the advice in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset)):

```golang
time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond) // Simulate reset work (delay could be partly dur to whatever is triggering the
if !to.Stop() {
    <-to.C
}
to.Reset(2 * time.Millisecond)
```

Try this in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/og-PrbXLuCd).

This works because `to.Stop` [returns](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) "true if the call stops the timer, false if the timer has already expired or been stopped". Note that things get a more complicated if the [timer is used in multiple go-routines](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) "This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's channel or other calls to the Timer's Stop method" but this is not the case in your use-case.

> Is my use of timer.Reset() unsafe, or are the cases mentioned in the Github issue highlighting other problems which are not applicable here?

Yes - it is unsafe. However the impact is fairly low. The event arriving and timer triggering would need to happen almost concurrently and, in that case, running the `remediate` code might not be a big issue. Note that the fix is fairly simple (as per the docs)

> If it is unsafe, is my second proposed solution acceptable (rebinding the timer on each iteration).

Your second proposed solution also works (but note that the garbage collector cannot free the timer until after it has fired, or been stopped, which may cause issues if you are creating timers rapidly).

Note: Re the suggestion from @JotaSantos

> Another thing that could be done is to add a select when draining <-to.C (on the Stop "if") with a default clause. That would prevent the pause.

See [this comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11513#issuecomment-142410578) for details of why this may not be a good approach (it's also unnecessary in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue. After reading a lot of information, I came up with a solution that goes along these lines:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const timeout = 2 * time.Second

    // Prepare a timer that is stopped and ready to be reset.
    // Stop will never return false, because an hour is too long
    // for timer to fire. Thus there's no need to drain timer.C.
    timer := time.NewTimer(timeout)
    timer.Stop()

    // Make sure to stop the timer when we return.
    defer timer.Stop()

    // This variable is needed because we need to track if we can safely reset the timer
    // in a loop. Calling timer.Stop() will return false on every iteration, but we can only
    // drain the timer.C once, otherwise it will deadlock.
    var timerSet bool

    c := make(chan time.Time)

    // Simulate events that come in every second
    // and every 5th event delays so that timer can fire.
    go func() {
        var i int
        ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        defer ticker.Stop()

        for t := range ticker.C {
            i++
            if i%5 == 0 {
                fmt.Println("Sleeping")
                time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
            }

            c <- t

            if i == 20 {
                break
            }
        }
        close(c)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case t, ok := <-c:
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Closed channel")
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("Got event", t, timerSet)

            // We got an event, and timer was already set.
            // We need to stop the timer and drain the channel if needed,
            // so that we can safely reset it later.
            if timerSet {
                if !timer.Stop() {
                    <-timer.C
                }
                timerSet = false
            }

            // If timer was not set, or it was stopped before, it's safe to reset it.
            if !timerSet {
                timerSet = true
                timer.Reset(timeout)
            }
        case remediate := <-timer.C:
            fmt.Println("Timeout", remediate)
            // It's important to store that timer is not set anymore.
            timerSet = false
        }
    }
}
```

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0QlujZngEGg